# How do I change the directory of the PowerShell cmd through a script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How would I go about doing what I mentioned in the subject line.  Here are screenshots of what I mean:

[image: before]

[image: script body]

I was expecting the directory below to have changed to "C:\Program Files" after running the "Test.ps1" script?

[image: after]

> Updated script after adding Write-Host $pwd

[image: Write-Host $pwd added to script]

Comment: If you want to change current location for current PowerShell instance, them you should not start new one: `.\Test.ps1`.

Comment: @PetSerAI could you clarify what you mean, as I don't quite understand what you're actually telling me?

Comment: @TimothyKruger The working directory of the script would be changed to the path entered. if you were to display the $pwd (print working directory) after the change directory command you would see that it would display that path.

Comment: @TimothyKruger, right then it means that any commands executed after the change would be run as though in that directory for the session

Comment: @Nkosi Ok great thanks for your replies, will do some more testing tomorrow when I'm at the office, as this was just a simple PowerShell script, where as the one I'm busy creating is already turning out to be a monster, as I'm pretty sure the $pwd was changed correctly based on your answers, but then my script has to run other scripts, and that's kind of where it actually errors out.  But the $pwd will come in very handy.

Comment: @TimothyKruger if you encapsulate that code into a function and call the function then it will change the directory when the function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global 'current' directory, it is a property of the particular process you are working in.  The 'current' directory for `winword.exe` may be very different to the 'current' directory of `powershell.exe`.  And indeed, two different powershell processes can have different ideas of the 'current' directory.

So it would be foolish to expect that changing the 'current' directory in one powershell process would affect any other processes.

Comment: Hey no problem.  It's a common misconception.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder"
```

The above will change the directory to the given location as long as you have access to navigate to the location provided.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if I'm running it from a *.ps1 script but works if I run it from the PowerShell cmd directly?

Comment: Everything I have researched so far shows that cd is correct. Are you getting any errors? The images you display appear as though they haven't been run.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think `Set-Location -Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder"` and `cd "C:\Folder\SubFolder"` do pretty much the same thing? So yeah the error is that it doesn't change the directory for the PowerShell script when using those cmds, as I've tried both...  Do you have an email addy you can share with me privately, then I can maybe email you with the scripts and the errors :D.

Comment: Tim from what I can see in the screenshots, you open PowerShell, then another screenshot is shown of the body of the script, then your third shows a console of you launching the script but nothing happening. Could you please add the following to your script (Write-Host $pwd) without the brackets and tell me what's displayed.

Comment: please see my updated script above after adding Write-Host $pwd.  I see the directory for $pwd is displaying "C:\Program Files" but why isn't the actual PS directory changing to "C:\Program Files"?